# ggplot does not show data in Shiny Plot (Warning: Removed k rows containing missing values (geom_point))

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, shiny, data-visualization

I have the following problem, when executing my Shiny App.
What I am trying, is to plot a simple dataset in ggplot. Firstly whether geom_point() or geom_line() is not important, but the input data should be the csv data set and the x-axis should be adjusted by the date range.

My Problem now is, that the ggplot is empty after uploading the data:

[image: empty ggplot]

and the warning message is the following:

```
Warning: Removed 8399 rows containing missing values (geom_point)
```

It doesn't appear when I replaced geom_point() by geom_line(), but the ggplot stays empty.

The full csv table can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xf7qtv7u2rcqdw9/sample_sales.csv?dl=0

The ui.R script is the following:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("My App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma = ',',
                   Semicolon = ';',
                   Tab = '\t'),
                   'Comma'),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None = '',
                   'Double Quote' = '"',
                   'Single Quote' = "'"),
                   'Double Quote'),
    dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                 start = "2009-01-01",
                 end = "2012-12-30")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Sales", plotOutput("sales")),
          tabPanel("Category", plotOutput("category")),
          tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("contents")))
        )
    )
)
```

and the server.R script looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    sales <- reactive({

        inFile <- input$file1

        if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

        read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
    })
    range <- reactive({
        c(input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2])
    })

    output$contents <- renderTable({
            print(head(sales()))
        })
    output$sales <- renderPlot({
        sales.df <- sales()
        sales.df$Order.Date <- as.Date(sales.df$Order.Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
        sales.df$Profit <- as.numeric(sales.df$Profit)
        y.limit = c(min(sales.df$Profit), max(sales.df$Profit))
        p <- ggplot(sales.df, aes(x = Order.Date, y = Profit)) + geom_point(size = 400) + scale_x_date(limits = c(input$daterange[1], input$daterange[2]))
        print(p)
        })

    output$category <- renderPlot({
        if (is.null(input$file1)) {
        return()
        }
        print(plot(sales()$sales[16]))
    })
})
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but the warning message suggests that your code sets one of the axis ranges to a region where there's no data. Or perhaps your code is accidentally changing, say, the date values in some way that they end up as `NA` or outside the x-range of the plot.

Comment: Yes, but the warning doesn't appear, when I replace **geom_point()** by **geom_line()** and the plot stays empty. Also after reviewing the data, all **sales.df$Profit** values should be in the plotted range.

Comment: Outside of your shiny app, in a regular R script, try running `as.Date(sales.df$Order.Date, "%Y/%m/%d")` and see what the output is. Remember that `"%Y/%m/%d"` is what you're telling `as.Date` about the format of the strings in `Order.Date`, not the format of the output of `as.Date`.

Comment: I was able to make it run with this change: `sales.df$Order.Date <- as.Date(as.character(sales.df$Order.Date, "%Y/%m/%d"))` and remove the point size parameter from geom_point. This should get you started. Probably you have to fix the date selection also...

Comment: @ValterBeaković you code is equivalent to just doing `as.Date(sales.df$Order.Date)`, because `sales.df$Order.Date` is already in character format and `as.character` ignores the `"%Y/%m/%d"`. Either one solves the problem because they don't provide an incorrect date format to `as.Date`.

Comment: @eipi10 when I run the code Odrer.Date is imported as factor. When run locally as.Date produces NA's adding as.character does not produce NA's...

Comment: Yes, your code does not produce NA, because you included `"%Y/%m/%d"` as an argument to `as.character` (and `as.character` ignores it) rather than as an argument to `as.Date`. Whether `Order.Date` is factor or character, `as.Date(sales.df$Order.Date)` will convert it to Date format. But if you include `"%Y/%m/%d"` in `as.Date` you'll get `NA` either way.

Comment: Clear, I guess than just the the date formatter should be changed to "%Y-%m-%d" since this is how the data is stored in the csv file.

Comment: Yes, but `as.Date` assumes that format anyway, so you don't need to add it.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot! It works finally! :)